# .Net Core 3 Deserializing List of object creates "empty" objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, json-deserialization

In my .Net Core 3.1 Web app I have a Class shared by Backend and Frontend that looks like this

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderTime { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int Vat { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public Dictionary<string, int> Products { get; set; }
    public int Discount { get; set; }
    public float ShippingPrice { get; set; }
    public bool Shipped { get; set; }
    public bool Cancelled { get; set; }
    public string CancelReason { get; set; }

    public Order()
    {

    }
}
```

And on Frontend I am using HttpClient to Get a list of Orders from REST API.

Json that the httpClient receives looks like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "orderTime": "2021-01-28T14:55:03.077",
        "userId": 0,
        "vat": 0,
        "products": null,
        "discount": 0,
        "shippingPrice": 0,
        "shipped": true,
        "cancelled": true,
        "cancelReason": "string"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "orderTime": "2021-01-28T14:55:03.077",
        "userId": 2,
        "vat": 0,
        "products": null,
        "discount": 10,
        "shippingPrice": 0,
        "shipped": false,
        "cancelled": false,
        "cancelReason": null
    }
]
```

And for deserialization I am using JsonSerializer:

```
var returnOrders = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Order>>(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
```

From that I do get the correct amount of objects on List, but all of them have values of 0 or null etc.
What am I doing wrong?

Before I was using ReadAsAsync() which worked fine, but is deprecated in .Net core 3

```
await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Object>>();
```

Comment: Have you checked the query you fire whether the `Order.Products` has value? I mean does your query `Include`s the mapped entities there? Is your data correct, I mean should be data there?

Comment: The Products are null on the database, do thats fine. But For example ID on all the objects is 0, which is not the case in the Json

Comment: So if you want different default value for `Order.Products` than null when there is no data there in the database then I would initiate `Order.Products` field int he constructor. As a result it will be a list having zero element. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood my issue here. The object I get from the deserialisation is different than the one in Json and Db. And it goes for the object or Order not specifically Order.Products

Comment: You need to make sure, that the spelling of your properties is the same as in the json file. If you want to use different spelling, then you have to use attributes to tell the json deserializer which property is which field in the json

Comment: Well, the class is shared between the Backend API and Frontend that consumes it so that should not be the issue. 
And if I add the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client and use the ReadAsAsync() method it works fine.

Comment: @Snackerino: I see it now.

Answer (score 6):

By default JsonSerializer look for properties in json with the same name as the one defined in your class. In your case you are using CamelCase naming convention, so you need to specify it like this:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
};
var returnOrders = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Order>>(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), options);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might happen due to JSON deserialization conventions used by different deserialisers. For instance some time the case of JSON keys matter.

Try using NewtonsoftJSON deserialiser instead of the default one your are using. It'll parse JSON without checking the case.

```
string json = @"{
'Email': 'james@example.com',
'Active': true,
'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
'Roles': [ 'User', 'Admin' ]
}";

Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);
Console.WriteLine(account.Email);
```

Comment: Well, I have the same class for Frontend and Backend and they both use the same Serializer in System.Text.Json.
If I use NewtonsoftJson that is used by Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client it works fine. I see no reason why it wouldn't deserialized  with System.Text.Json when it was serialized with it.

Comment: I got your point and you are completely right. However the point I'm trying to make is the way different deserialiser handles the JSON parsing. I've faced not same although similar issue an year back and resolved by switching my JSON parser. @Snackerino